# How to load string.xml for indian languages in android?

Tags: android, localization

I am trying to load strings.xml files for following Indian languages:

1. Oriya (values-or)
2. Bengali (values-bn)
3. Punjabi (values-pa)
4. Gujarati (values-gu)
5. Marathi (values-mr)
6. Malayalam (values-ml)
7. Telugu (values-te)
8. Tamil (values-ta)
9. Kannada (values-kn)

and tried with `values-or-rIN,..etc` as well. and using following code to load locale:

```
public void changeLang(String lang) {
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (!"".equals(lang) && !config.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
            ed.putString(getString(R.string.locale_lang), lang);
            ed.commit();

            locale = new Locale(lang);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration conf = new Configuration(config);
            conf.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString(this.getString(R.string.locale_lang), lang);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
```

Above code is working for all international languages. but not for above-mentioned languages. I saw many answers, as per them we need to load fonts ttf files of the corresponding language. But I don't want to load fonts (TypeFace). I want to load strings.xml.

Could anyone suggest how to load strings.xml of Indian languages? Is it possible? or Should I go for fonts ttf for above-mentioned languages??

Comment: just create folder with values-gu .... and in code put gu for gujarati

Comment: i mentioned that i have already did that but getting only english text. working only for hindi and english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this for Gujarati language:

```
        Locale myLocale = new Locale("gu");
        Resources res =  getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Change "gu" with other language name
I am using Gujarati in my app. This working perfectly

Comment: great, its working fine. but one question i am not able to understand our code is almost same, only i am calling getResource() from getBaseContext().getResource(), nothing else. otherwise i was doing everything same.

Comment: i think getbaseContext not work in whole app, try to use getApplicationContext

Comment: Not working for me I am using  `Eureka` device with `kitkat`

Answer (score 2):

**I had done this following way:**

```
    String lang = "ml";//for malyalam language

    if(lang.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.text_item_ml))) {
              lang = Constants.LANGUAGE_CODE_MALAYALAM;
              country = Constants.COUNTRY_CODE_INDIA;
         }

    Locale locale;
    if (country == null) {
       locale = new Locale(lang);
      } else {
              locale = new Locale(lang, country);
             }
      Locale.setDefault(locale);
      Configuration config = new Configuration();
      config.locale = locale;
      getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
onConfigurationChanged(config);
```

And values folder name should be:

values-ml-rIN

values-gu-rIN

If your phone not supporting particular character then only you need font other wise no need custom font, I made application which is supporting 12 indian local language without any custom font.

Check that your phone supported particular lang or not using below method

```
public static boolean isSupported(Context context, String text) {
        final int WIDTH_PX = 200;
        final int HEIGHT_PX = 80;

        int w = WIDTH_PX, h = HEIGHT_PX;
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
        Bitmap orig = bitmap.copy(conf, false);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        paint.setTextSize((int) (14 * scale));

        // draw text to the Canvas center
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
        int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2;

        canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
        boolean res = !orig.sameAs(bitmap);
        orig.recycle();
        bitmap.recycle();
        return res;
    }
```

Hope It will help you !

Comment: what is `text` in `isSupported()` this method that you are passing.

Comment: And I am using folder name as `values-gu`  and Not working for me I am using `Eureka`  device with `kitkat`.

Comment: @Sagar sorry for late reply, Here text means string in specific language eg. 
 To check "Hindi" lang is supported so it should call like this  isSupported(context,"
हिंदी").

Comment: @Sagar Have you found any fix to support the language in Kitkat.

Comment: @Srinivasan we are targeting device above `kitkat` showing only supported languages